# How to reach internal cloud run services from a different project and his own?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I am currently stuck on a network architecture issue on Google Cloud Platform.

Let me explain:

I have a project A with different Google Cloud Run services which are all restricted with an internal ingress (without authorization from external load balancer). All project A services have an internal load balancer with an ip address from the default network. Another project B is exactly set up in the same way and I would like to reach project A service **AND** project B service from project B.

I set up a Shared VPC with a specific subnet created in project A and shared with project B. From what I know, I have to set up a Serverless VPC connector in the project B service to reach any internal addresses. So, from project B, If I use a Serverless VPC which uses its own default network I can't reach project A services (time out) but I can reach his own. Otherwise If I use a project A Serverless VPC I can reach project A services but not his own (time out).

This whole situation makes sense but is it possible to create (with VPC Network Peering ?) a special VPC connector which uses only the shared subnet to route only internal addresses from project A and uses the other subnets from project B to route his own services ?

Comment: What's your egress configuration? Internal or All traffic?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I did not configure anything for egress. However I can reach external api

Comment: Ok, it should be the problem. Set the egress to all traffic, with CLI add that parameter `--vpc-egress=all-traffic`. And let me know if it's better. If so, I will answer the question with more detail on the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the right way to do this with [Private Service Connect](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-service-connect).
Just need to publish a service in the project A and connect an endpoint in the project B. All this without any Shared VPC configuration or anything else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).